# React Native Reanimated 2 Entering Animations doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to use https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/LayoutAnimations/entryAnimations

From the documentation it seems pretty simple but when I run the code below nothing happens:

```
...
import Animated, { AnimatedLayout, FadeInRight } from "react-native-reanimated";

...
  return (
    <Animated.View
      entering={FadeInRight.delay(3000)}>
    ...
    </Animated.View>
```

In my package.json I'm using "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0-beta.3".

What am I missing? Is there some recommended tutorial on this topic?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. They are no longer supporting remote debugging. Turning off the remote debugging worked for me.

They mention it in their documentation but it is not highlighted.
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/next/#known-problems-and-limitations

Answer (score 1):

Been trying it out for a very long time. This thing just doesn't work and it is frustrating